# MFC Serialize doubly linked list

Tags: c++, serialization, mfc, doubly-linked-list

I made a doubly linked list in my MFC program.
Whenever I want to load the variables, the program crashes. I cant create a new Node.
Does anyone know how to Serialize a doubly linked list.

Here is my function:

```
void CDatenbankDoc::Serialize(CArchive& ar)
{
    if (ar.IsStoring())
    {
        Actual = Start;
        while (Actual)
        {   
            ar << Actual->name;
            ar << Actual->adresse;
            ar << Actual->email;
            ar << Actual->fax;
            ar << Actual->firma;
            ar << Actual->geburtsdatum;
            ar << Actual->geschlecht;
            ar << Actual->land;
            ar << Actual->ort;
            ar << Actual->plz;
            ar << Actual->telefon;
            ar << Actual->vorname;
            Actual = Actual->next;      
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Actual = Start;
        while (InsertedAll != true)
        {
            Actual->next = new Node;
            Actual->next->previous = Actual;
            ar >> Actual->next->name;
            ar >> Actual->next->vorname;
            ar >> Actual->next->adresse;
            ar >> Actual->next->email;
            ar >> Actual->next->fax;
            ar >> Actual->next->firma;
            ar >> Actual->next->geburtsdatum;
            ar >> Actual->next->geschlecht;
            ar >> Actual->next->land;
            ar >> Actual->next->ort;
            ar >> Actual->next->plz;
            ar >> Actual->next->telefon;
            Actual = Actual->next;
            if (!Actual->next)
            {
                InsertedAll = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your basic problem is that when you store the linked list you do not store anything that indicates when the list ends. I'm not sure what magic you are expecting to happen when you read this list back. How about storing the *length* of the list first. Then your read routine can use this value to tell when to stop reading.

Comment: are you sure about the `  Actual = Actual->next;` without any checking?

Comment: The best way to know when the list ends is to traverse the list first and get the number of members. Write this first into the stream. That's the way like all other MFC container use the archive stream.

Comment: Can someone explain me this with code? I pretty new to MFC so I dont really know what exactly to do

Comment: And you are pretty new to C and C++ as well I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below. I've not tested it, so there might be some errors, but you should get the idea.
I assume that Start is a member of CDatenbankDoc.

```
int CDatenbankDoc::GetLinkedListSize()
{
  // This function returns the length of the linked list whose 1st element 
  // is pointed by the Start member.
  // The implementation is left as an exercice

}    

void CDatenbankDoc::Serialize(CArchive& ar)
{
    if (ar.IsStoring())
    {
        ar << GetLinkedListSize(Start) ;  // save size of linked list

        Actual = Start;
        while (Actual)
        {   
            ar << Actual->name;
            ar << Actual->adresse;
            ...
            Actual = Actual->next;      
        }
    }
    else
    {
        int size ;
        ar >> size ;   // get size of linked list

        Node *previous = NULL ;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            Node *Actual = new Node;     // assuming Node constructor inits
                                         // pointers to Null                
            if (previous)
                previous->next = actual ;

            Actual->previous = previous ;

            if (i == 0)
              Start = Actual ;

            // beware, the order of serialisation and deserialisazion must 
            // be the same during reading and writing which is not the case
            // in the code you posted !!!

            ar >> Actual->name;
            ar >> Actual->adresse;
            ...

            previous = Actual ;
        }
    }
}
```

A better solution would be to encapsulate your linked list into a class that has a Serialize member fonction.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if (!Actual->next)` accesses a value that hasn't been initialized.